# how to get the id from First API to utilize in nested call of another API, using retrofit in android Studio?

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to fetch the genre's id from the response of GenresDataModel and want that id to compare with nested api response of MovieDataModel.

Here I've Created an interface method for call retrofit api. where I've called

```
@GET("3/discover/movie")
    Call<MovieDataModel> MOVIE_DATA_MODEL_CALL(
            @QueryMap HashMap<String, String> params
    );
```

For example, first API contains data of Genres with id and name.

```
{
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Adventure"
        }
    ]
}
```

And second API has the data which I need to compare in nested API.

```
"release_date": "2013-08-30",
"genre_ids": [
     99,
     10402
  ],
```

[The Genre API Model is create, and Set the parameter for second API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBm1B.png)

[In the call of second API, I'm not able to compare the genres Id with movieGenreId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Pqc.png)

I've tried to store this in Hashmap, however it got failed for on data type with respect to object , list as well as for String.

**What I'm suppose to do?**
to get the id from the response of first API & to compare them in nested(Second API response) response of another API with "GenresId".

Answer (score 0):

Naming of the function is off, rename it to `fun getMovieData()` instead  `MOVIE_DATA_MODEL_CALL`
You need Retrofit to return a `Flow` then use `flatMap` to call the other.

`service.getMovieData().flatMap { service.getSecondCall(it.id) }`

Comment: Thanks @Nikola, but this is in Kotlin, however I'm using the Java technology to develop the app.  In my Application, I've used achieved it using first API call in it, I've made a **for loop** to pass the genres result data with respect to id. to pass it in api call.

`for (int i = 0; i < genreResults.size(); i++) {
                    params.put("api_key", URLs.API_KEY);
                    params.put("with_genres", String.valueOf(genreResults.get(i).getId()));`

and called the second API, and set the response using, 

`genreResults.get(finalI).setMovieResults(movieResults);`